# What's the price for dying?

Tags: path-of-exile

What happens when you die ?  Is there any sort of penalty ?  I think that I didn't lost any XP or items after my last death.  Mobs did not respawn, the map I discovered remained discovered...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Standard league:***

Experience loss depends on the difficulty you're currently playing in. Note you cannot lose levels by losing experience through death.

- Normal Difficulty: 0%
- Cruel Difficulty: 5%
- Merciless Difficulty: 10%

***Hardcore league:***

The character is removed from the hardcore league (temporary or permanent). The character and all the items they are carrying are transferred to the permanent Standard league.

***Cut-throat league:***

Items are dropped upon death, making them loot-able for anyone. You also lose experience at the same rate as Standard leagues.

[source](http://pathofexile.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Death_penalty)

Comment: It's not possible to lose a level.

Comment: Switched hard difficulty to normal, as in the beta the names where wierd, got mixed up. Hope this clears everything out for you.

Comment: Cut-throat league also makes you lose 30% exp and gives it to your killer.

Comment: Just another question: no penalties on gems' experience ?

Comment: @Anto Gems do not lose XP when you die. Quite the contrary, dieing often will result in not being able to level some gems because you are behind their XP curve and thus their required level for leveling up is too high.

Comment: I believe you also lose all summons (and get transported back to town losing time traveling). The loss of summons is annoying if you specialize in spectres since you need to go re-harvest them.

Comment: This link also mentions loss of resistances, is that correct? http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Difficulty

Comment: This is out of date as of v3.0, in that “difficulties” no longer exist. Now the penalties are 0% in Part I, 5% in Part II, and 10% in the Epilogue (maps). It’s also worth noting that PvP does not apply any of the normal or hardcore penalties.