# Can you level down?

Tags: path-of-exile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the price for dying?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102661/whats-the-price-for-dying)

Path of Exile mentions that death carries experience penalties on high difficulty levels. Can the experience penalty incur in a level down? What if you already had allocated your passive skill point?

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102675/15726) and its first comment, death cannot make you lose a level.

> Losing levels: Experience lost in this way will never cause a character to drop down a level.

Source: http://pathofexile.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Death_penalty

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot lose a level by incurring the experience penalty upon death. Worst case is you lose all your XP accumulated at your current level and therefore having 0% XP at your current level.